# SQLiteException: no such column: (code 1)

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the below method that when executed gives the error:

> 11-09 12:11:17.578: E/AndroidRuntime(21018): Caused by:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: happy (code
>   1): , while compiling: select * from Bank where english = happy

The method is:

```
public boolean BankHas(Word currentWord) {
        openDataBase();
        Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("select * from Bank where english = " + currentWord.english, null); 
        return cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
```

My table scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE `Bank` (
    `english`   TEXT
);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you missed single quote,so change

```
"select * from Bank where english = " + currentWord.english
```

to

```
"select * from Bank where english ='" + currentWord.english + "'"
```

Or **recommended solution** is to use **parameterized query** as

```
Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("select * from Bank where english =? ", new String [] {currentWord.english});
```

And change your create table from

```
CREATE TABLE `Bank` (
    `english`   TEXT
);
```

to

```
CREATE TABLE Bank (
    english TEXT
);
```